# MarsRover in Scala

Tags: beginner, scala

This is my first attempt at Scala programming. I tried to be functional but I'm not sure if I have achieved that.

***DataTypes.scala***

```
object DataTypes {

  case class Position(xPos: Int, yPos: Int)

  sealed trait Direction

  case object N extends Direction

  case object S extends Direction

  case object E extends Direction

  case object W extends Direction

  case class RoverState(direction: Direction, position: Position)

  val leftRotation = Map[Direction, Direction](N -> W, W -> S, S -> E, E -> N)
  val rightRotation = Map[Direction, Direction](N -> E, W -> N, S -> W, E -> S)

}
```

***RoverMachine.scala:***

```
import DataTypes._

object RoverMachine {

  def initialRoverState(direction: Direction, position: Position): RoverState = {
    RoverState(direction, position)
  }

  def move(roverState: RoverState): RoverState = {
    roverState.direction match {
      case N => RoverState(N, Position(roverState.position.xPos, roverState.position.yPos + 1))
      case S => RoverState(S, Position(roverState.position.xPos, roverState.position.yPos - 1))
      case E => RoverState(E, Position(roverState.position.xPos + 1, roverState.position.yPos))
      case W => RoverState(W, Position(roverState.position.xPos - 1, roverState.position.yPos))
    }
  }

  def leftTurn(roverState: RoverState): RoverState = {
    RoverState(leftRotation.get(roverState.direction).get, roverState.position)
  }

  def rightTurn(roverState: RoverState): RoverState = {
    RoverState((rightRotation.get(roverState.direction)).get, roverState.position)
  }
}
```

***RoverApp.scala***

```
import DataTypes._
import RoverMachine._

import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

object RoverApp extends App {

  println("Enter Direction")

  def parseToDirection(direction: String): Direction = {
    direction match {
      case "N" => N
      case "S" => S
      case "E" => E
      case "W" => W
    }
  }

  val initialDirection: Direction = parseToDirection(readLine())
  println("Enter XPosition")
  val initialXPosition: Int = readLine().toInt
  println("Enter YPosition")
  val initialYPosition: Int = readLine().toInt
  println("Enter Instructions")
  val instructionList: Array[Char] = readLine().toCharArray

  var roverState = initialRoverState(N, Position(initialXPosition, initialYPosition))

  for (instruction <- instructionList) {
    instruction match {
      case 'M' => roverState = move(roverState)
      case 'L' => roverState = leftTurn(roverState)
      case 'R' => roverState = rightTurn(roverState)
    }
  }

  println(roverState.direction + " " + roverState.position.xPos + ", " + roverState.position.yPos)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Suggestions

1. For all your direction `case object` hierarchy, you are basically trying to duplicate an enum, which Scala provides no language-level support for. However, Scala does provide support for enumerations at the API level via the `Enumeration` class, which should be extended by new enums.

   You could try something like this:

   ```
   object Directions extends Enumeration {
     type Direction = Value
     val N, S, E, W = Value
   }
   ```

   and then your `parseToDirection(String)` method becomes unnecessary and can be replaced with a `Direction.withName(String)`, a method for retrieving enum constants by name defined in `Enumeration`. You will also need to update your method signatures involving `Direction` to `Directions.Direction`, and add an `import Directions._` before every piece of code in a given scope which uses a `Direction`, i.e., one import before declaring the rotation `Map`s, one in `RoverMachine` (this makes the `get()` call on the value unnecessary in the rotation methods), and one in `RoverApp`.

   However, this might complicate the code a bit and reduce the type safety offered by exhaustive pattern matching, however.

   **TL;DR** Your approach with a `sealed trait` and `case object`s is the preferred one in Scala, this is just an alternative. Note, you could also as well used a Java enum for this purpose too.
2. The one `var` in `main()` clouds the functional-ness of the code a bit. You could replace the loop with a recursive inner method in `main`, but there's always a better solution. Read to the end for a cohesive correction of your code.
3. `String` in Scala can be treated to inherit `Seq[Char]`, as `String` has an implicit conversion to `StringOps`, which is a subclass of `Seq[Char]`, so you don't need to convert the `instructionList` to an `Array[Char]` before looping over it, you can use it directly as a `String`.
4. `Map.apply()` is semantically the same as `Map.get()`, so use the former as it allows the syntactic sugar of making the entire call look like the following:

   ```
   def leftTurn(roverState: RoverState): RoverState = {
     RoverState(leftRotation(roverState.direction), roverState.position)
   }
   ```

   (similarly for `rightTurn(RoverState)`)
5. Rely on type inference: In Scala, it is unnecessary to declare the types of most values, as they can be inferred by the compiler, and this does not decrease the readability of your code much unless the declaration is extremely complicated or the inferred type is unintuitive/incorrect.

   This makes your value declarations in `main()` look like (incorporating some of my other suggestions:

   ```
   val initialDirection = Directions.withName(readLine())
   val initialXPosition = readLine().toInt
   val initialYPosition = readLine().toInt
   val instructionList = readLine()
   ```

   Also, in `DataTypes`, you can skip the generic type specification for the `Map[Direction,Direction]` and write just `Map`, the compiler will infer the generic types.
6. The code to move the rover should be a part of the `RoverMachine`, not `RoverApp`. Also, it should be defined as a function like this:
7. Drop the surrounding braces in one-line functions, it makes the code look more functional.
8. No exception handling - What to do if the user enters illegal characters? Scala is infamous for its confusing stack traces, it would be good to define code to handle exceptional conditions - a functional (recursive) equivalent of running the entire `main()` block in a `while` loop which breaks only on legal input. Also, consider throwing proper exceptions in exceptional cases, an example is in point 6.
9. Imports should be declared closest to their site of use.
10. There is code duplication between `leftTurn()` and `rightTurn()`. You could probably use a `turn()` function accepting a type of turn, be it indicated by a `Boolean` flag, an enum constant (I use this approach in the code below), or a `case object` hierarchy. Pattern match on the type of turn to choose the correct rotations `Map` to use.

## Style

**Naming:**

You name your side-effect-free functions in a way which makes users think that they have side-effects. Instead of naming them with present-tense verbs, name them with past-tense verbs, like `turned` instead of `turn`, `moved` instead of `move`, etc.

Your indentation and bracket usage are spot-on unless otherwise noted.

## Errors

1. In  `main()`, you initialize `roverState` as

   `var roverState = initialRoverState(N, Position(initialXPosition, initialYPosition))`

   The initial direction is always `N`; although you accept the initial direction as an input, you never use it. That line should be

   `var roverState = initialRoverState(initialDirection, Position(initialXPosition, initialYPosition))`

## Rant

You hadn't tried much to be functional. If you had, then not even a single `var`, mutable data structure or loop would have turned up in your code, but all 3 did, so...

Most programmers hate global state, and for good reason. if there were any `var`s in your `DataTypes` `object`, it would have been a mess in the making. Thankfully, it is just a declaration of constants, so no problem there.

## My take on your code

The final code, which is very functional and handles errors using `Option` (real error handling should use `Either` to retain error information, but AFAIK it's provided by `scalaz`, which I don't have), follows. I put it all into one file, as Scala allows that.

```
object DataTypes {
  case class Position(xPos: Int, yPos: Int)

  object Directions extends Enumeration {
    type Direction = Value
    val N, S, E, W = Value
  }

  case class RoverState(direction: Directions.Direction, position: Position)

  import Directions._
  val leftRotation = Map(N -> W, W -> S, S -> E, E -> N)
  val rightRotation = Map(N -> E, W -> N, S -> W, E -> S)

  object Turns extends Enumeration {
    type Turn = Value
    val Left, Right = Value
  }
}

object RoverMachine {
  import DataTypes._
  def initialRoverState(direction: Directions.Direction, position: Position) = Some(RoverState(direction, position))

  import Directions._
  def moved(state: Option[RoverState]) = state match {
    case Some(roverState) => roverState.direction match {
      case N => Some(RoverState(N, Position(roverState.position.xPos, roverState.position.yPos + 1)))
      case S => Some(RoverState(S, Position(roverState.position.xPos, roverState.position.yPos - 1)))
      case E => Some(RoverState(E, Position(roverState.position.xPos + 1, roverState.position.yPos)))
      case W => Some(RoverState(W, Position(roverState.position.xPos - 1, roverState.position.yPos)))
    }
    case None => None
  }

  import Turns._
  def turned(state: Option[RoverState], turn: Turns.Turn) = state match {
    case Some(roverState) => Some(RoverState(turn match {
                                              case Left => leftRotation(roverState.direction)
                                              case Right => rightRotation(roverState.direction)
                                            }, roverState.position))
    case None => None
    }

  def travelled(state: Option[RoverState], instructions: Seq[Char]): Option[RoverState] = state match {
    case Some(roverState) => instructions match {
      case Seq() => state
      case head +: tail => travelled(head match {
      //also added support for lower case characters in the instructions String
        case 'M'|'m' => moved(state)
        case 'L'|'l' => turned(state, Turns.Left)
        case 'R'|'r' => turned(state, Turns.Right)
        case other => None
      }, tail)
    }
    case None => None
  }
}

object RoverApp extends App {
  import DataTypes._
  import RoverMachine._
  import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

  println("Enter Direction")

  val initialDirection = Directions.withName(readLine())
  println("Enter XPosition")
  val initialXPosition = readLine().toInt
  println("Enter YPosition")
  val initialYPosition = readLine().toInt
  println("Enter Instructions")
  val instructions = readLine()

  val state = travelled(initialRoverState(initialDirection, Position(initialXPosition, initialYPosition)), instructions)

  state match {
    case Some(roverState) => println(roverState.direction + " " + roverState.position.xPos + ", " + roverState.position.yPos)
    case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException("There were illegal characters in the Command String")
    }
}
```

I have left off the return types of non-recursive functions as the compiler can infer them, and they are not unintuitive enough to hurt readability.

**Edit:**

In response to @leoOrion's comment about pattern matching and value bindings, i think I should explain what the following piece of code actually does.

```
    instructions match {
      case Seq() => ... //matches the empty _Seq_uence
      case head :+ tail => ... //binds the head of the _Seq_uence to `head` and the tail to `tail` (similarly to pattern matching on lists). Read below.
      ...
    }
```

Pattern matching in functional languages is a very powerful construct, much more so than the simple `switch-case` in most imperative languages. The clauses in a pattern matching expression (a `match` expression in Scala), match the patterns in the clause against the input argument(s) (and, optionally, also bind values to the results of the match).

In Scala, pattern matching clauses are denoted by the starting `case` keyword, which often occludes beginners from the power of pattern matching. Hence, both `Seq()` and `head :+ tail` denote patterns to matched against the argument, which in this case is the `instructions` `Seq`. Now, `Seq()` just matches the empty `Seq`, as would `Nil` for an empty `List`, and `head :+ tail` for `Seq`s is the exact equivalent of `head :: tail` for `List`s. This pattern not only matches the "head" (the first element of a list or sequence) and "tail" (the rest of that list or sequence), it also binds the values `head` and `tail` to the results of that matching, in respective order. So, `head :+ tail` would cause `head` to contain the first element of the `instructions` `Seq`, and `tail` to contain the rest of that `Seq`, allowing for easily described recursion over the sequence.

***Note:***

The `case class` `:+` for pattern matching on `Seq`s in general is only available in Scala 2.10+. I use 2.11, and I guess the OP uses that or higher too. For a lower Scala version, this behaviour can be emulated by converting the `Seq` to a `List` before the pattern match with `.toList`, or by making a custom implicit wrapper for `Seq` containing the appropriate extractor (`unapply()`) method.

Comment: You could also handle errors using exceptions.

Comment: Also, I don't find the recursive call to `travelled` to be a very readable.  It's difficult to tell where the first argument ends and the second one begins.

Comment: @Nathan I did mention using exceptions to signal error conditions in point 6. My code uses `Option` as that's the functional way of doing it, as the OP was trying.

Comment: @Nathan, in the implementation of traveled I was trying to minimise value declarations too, as much as possible, to stay on the "functional" path. However, maybe that was a bit overdoing it, but Scala's `PartialFunction` power is well illustrated here. Anyway, there's proper indentation, so it shouldn't be that much of a problem. Maybe the closing brace?

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Although I disagree with the implication that exceptions are any less functional that `Option` or similar alternatives.

Comment: @Nathan If that was indeed the case, then why would functional programming languages try to avoid using exceptions as much as possible and try to wrap up error conditions in various Option/Either types?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdury, All I know is that exceptions are functional effects, since they can be modeled in a functional manner both with monads and delimited continuations.  So I don't see any reason to regard exceptions as anything other than functional.

Comment: `case head +: tail => travelled(head match {`. In this line what does 'head' and 'tail' mean ??

Comment: @NathanDavis I see your point there, and I agree, however, wrapping exception information into an `Either` datatype is what conventionally people consider as "functional", monads and delimited continuations being used to model an exceptional condition seems like too much effort for too little gain in a (especially pure) functional language. The point being, yes, exceptions aren't out-of-place in a functional language, but with algebraic data types, there are easier ways to handle exceptional conditions (which is why I advocate Scala having an `Either` type in its standard library.

Comment: @leoOrion `head` and `tail` are variable to which the results of a pattern match on the `instructions` `Seq` are bound. (Pattern matching is more than a glorified `switch-case`, as you will soon realize if you continue with Scala). `head` contains the first element of the `instructions` `Seq`, while `tail` will contain the rest of the `Seq` (everything in the `Seq`uence other than the first element).